# What does it mean in practice that Putin and Lavrov will be personally on EU's sanctions list?

Tags: european-union, russian-federation, sanctions

https://tass.com/politics/1411353

> The European Union is going to include into the sanction list Russian President Vladimir Putin and Foreign Minister Sergey Lavrov, German Foreign Minister Annalena Baerbock said.

So what will that mean in practice? The won't be able to travel to any place in the EU, despite diplomatic passports?

Comment: And their wealth will be frozen. (Except for the billions they might have in Switzerland. :))

Comment: That’s going to depend on what sanctions are on the list. I’m pretty sure that hasn’t been decided yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has taken the form of including Putin and Lavrov in the Annex to [Council Regulation No 269/2014](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32014R0269&from=EN) of 17 March 2014, “concerning restrictive measures in respect of actions undermining or threatening the territorial integrity, sovereignty and independence of Ukraine”.

[Council Implementing Regulation (EU) 2022/332](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32022R0332&qid=1645830044413&from=EN) published in the evening of February 25th amended the Annex, adding the two, along with many members of the State Duma who supported the recognition of the LPR/DPR.

The sanctions are set out in Article 2 of the Regulation, and state:

> 1. All funds and economic resources belonging to, owned, held or controlled by any natural persons or natural or legal persons, entities or bodies associated with them as listed in Annex I shall be frozen.
> 2. No funds or economic resources shall be made available, directly or indirectly, to or for the benefit of natural persons or natural or legal persons, entities or bodies associated with them listed in Annex I.

There are also various exemptions written into the asset freezing article, for example if they are “necessary to satisfy the basic needs of the persons listed in the Annex and their dependent family members”.

Answer (score 4):

[News reports](https://www.politico.eu/article/eu-plans-to-freeze-russia-vladimir-putin-and-sergey-lavrov-assets/) say that there are explicitly no travel restrictions, so that talks are not precluded. Consider the Russian [offer](https://www.tagesschau.de/ausland/europa/russland-ukraine-verhandlungen-101.html) of holding talks in 'neutral' Belarus. Such talks would have a different tone from talks in Geneva, Paris, or New York, which is why Russia is suggesting Minsk.

That leaves attempts to freeze assets held in the West. Putin's wealth is [disputed](https://fortune.com/2022/02/25/putin-net-worth-wealth-russia-ukraine-invasion-sanctions-biden-us/), but it may be high.

Comment: I guess TASS didn't find it worthwhile to mention that travel restrictions were not included. Can you link you one such? Your first link, in German, doesn't quite seem to say that.

Comment: @Fizz, the 'offer' link was about the talks offer. I'll add a 'reports' link.

Comment: "... in the West" is a bit unclear what the West is for this answer. It's only the EU, so no UK or Norway or Switzerland for example.

Comment: "...but it may be high." This is very speculative. It also may be low or it may be high but hidden somewhere else.

Answer (score 3):

Let's admit, it will be difficult to restrict travel if a meeting is held between Putin and say Macron in Paris. Other than that, the other "punishments" might follow.

It is described [here](https://www.consilium.europa.eu/en/press/press-releases/2022/02/23/russian-recognition-of-the-non-government-controlled-areas-of-the-donetsk-and-luhansk-oblasts-of-ukraine-as-independent-entities-eu-adopts-package-of-sanctions/)

> Restrictive measures include an asset freeze and a prohibition from making funds available to the listed individuals and entities. In addition, a travel ban applicable to the listed persons prevents these from entering or transiting through EU territory.

Comment: It seems the high-level Russian figures will subjected to a different set of bans than the "grunts" from Donbass. No travel ban, for instance. See my own answer for a quote.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, apparently o.m. is correct and [no travel ban](https://www.dw.com/en/eu-foreign-ministers-consider-sanctions-on-putin-lavrov/a-60919147) was envisaged so far.

> Travel ban on Putin, Lavrov not expected yet
>
> Austrian Foreign Minister Alexander Schallenberg said the bloc would move forward with freezing the bank accounts of Putin and Lavrov, but added that a EU travel ban for the two leaders was not up for discussion.
>
> "There will be no travel ban against them, though, because we want to retain the possibility of negotiations in order to end the violence in Ukraine," Schallenberg said in Brussels.

---

Anyway, the [point](https://www.bbc.com/news/live/world-europe-60517447?ns_mchannel=social&ns_source=twitter&ns_campaign=bbc_live&ns_linkname=62191daeec502b53cd47fa58%26EU%20sanctions%20Putin%20and%20Lavrov%262022-02-25T18%3A20%3A26.283Z&ns_fee=0&pinned_post_locator=urn:asset:ecfce8a2-12ba-4be2-b808-450e52e7dd4b&pinned_post_asset_id=62191daeec502b53cd47fa58&pinned_post_type=share) that the EU seems to be making is that it's a symbolic thing by emphasizing who else on that level is on the list

> The BBC understands it's an asset freeze and not a travel ban. We don't know the details of assets that would potentially be affected, or indeed if either man has assets in the EU.
>
> "Let me flag that the only leaders in the world that are sanctioned by the European Union are Assad from Syria, Lukashenko from Belarus and now Putin from Russia," EU foreign policy chief Josep Borrell says.

Interestingly, the US [has](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-60530171) imposed a travel ban too.