# Are sanctions on Putin more of a symbolical gesture or do they actually mean something?

Tags: sanctions, vladimir-putin

US and EU have sanctioned Putin today. Although the reasons are clear, based on my limited understanding this seems more like a symbolical gesture.

Here is why it seems to me like this:

- I doubt that he personally needs money (or even remembers how they look like). He is one of the most powerful people in the world and as long as he remains in power, he has anything he needs
- In comparison to russian oligarchs (whos assets are still hard to track), Putin's assets outside of Russia are probably extremely hard to find. And the assets in Russia are beyond the reach.

So my question is: what are the real implications of those sanctions besides showing a clear message to smaller fish in his surrounding (If we are going for a big guy, we are clearly serious), somehow hurt his ego.

I have seen this question [What does it mean in practice that Putin and Lavrov will be personally on EU's sanctions list?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/71072/what-does-it-mean-in-practice-that-putin-and-lavrov-will-be-personally-on-eus-s) and do not think it answers my question

Comment: (+1) That's an interesting way to phrase the question: Symbols do mean something, that's even what they are for. Now, if those particular santions achieve anything else than having meaning, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

It accomplishes primarily 3 things.

- It provides incentive to the aggressor to stop, with the implicit promise that the sanctions will be rolled back if they do. Hence it is a way to gain additional leverage over the aggressor. The size of that leverage and how much of an incentive it really provides, is up for debate.
- It's a way for politicians and other people to act like they're acting without actually doing something drastic, such as military intervention or more drastic sanctions (ones that would also hurt the sanctioning part, i.e. think of gas prices). This is why you've heard more about what's going to happen to football games or F1 races, than you have about what the world plans to do about Russian gas dependency. Because it's about coming off as being anti-Russian and showing solidarity with Ukraine - not about actually being so.
- It's hurts the sanctioned party and destabilizes their economy and infrastructure. This can potentially lead to a political upset, causing a new governing party to be established in that country, one that may be more friendly to the rest of the world.

Comment: The last point sounds very opinion based.

Comment: I disagree with point 3 as that all depends on where they have their money and how much planning they did for the sanctions.

Comment: @convert, the last point is strongly supported by talks of EU leaders, which appeal to Russian citizens, they are basically ask Russians to change their government.

Comment: @klm123 So jus because the EU don´t like the russian government it must be changed?

Comment: @convert, I'm not sure what you imply, but I said a different thing. Indeed, this can be considered as strong evidence that EU thinks that russian government must be changed at any cost. Which would be still a speculation and off-topic statement. I was talking specifically about reasons behind EU sanctions. Sanctions do help to destabilize russian's opinion and may lead to internal conflicts within Russia, which would help EU.

Comment: @convert the idea is to make Russians not like their government, if they are mature enough to do so.

Comment: @MrVocabulary Why should russians not like their government, if the West is the one imposing that sanctions and not the government.

Comment: @convert The result (sanctions and military losses) are a direct response of Russian leadership's decision (military aggression), a mature society should be able to see the causal relationship, especially that condition to reverse that situation (lift the sanctions and stop dealing damage to Russian military) has been directly communicated. The global response is not a result of having a day day and throwing a tantrum, but an action that even Russia's biggest allies won't support on international stage, and I believe Russians are able to make that connection.

Comment: @Convert: At minimum, it essentially is like political scandals that lead to a vote of no confidence motion in a parliamentary democracy. If the opposition can use "The reason these sanctions are in place is because of the leading party", it's a sign that they may want to force an election to gain support.

Only this time - the *economic outlook* of the country **because** of the actions that caused the sanctions is the scandal. Like tying Watergate to a cause for an economic downturn, with some scales a bit off.

Comment: @MrVocabulary This strange western logic is not working in Russia, like it´s not working in any country under western sanctions.

Answer (score 2):

> this seems more like a symbolical gesture

It's not just symbolic. There are real restrictions of his freedom. All the things that are sanctioned are now really denied to him. He can do less than he could do before. That is a real effect.

What you seem to ask is how much Putin does actually care about them? Well that nobody can answer with certainty, except Putin himself. And in particular his wealth that may now be frozen, nobody knows how much it is, so the effect of that is completely unknown and we should not pretend otherwise.

I agree that the personal sanction does not take away Putin's ability to be Russia's strong men and influence Russia's fate and wreak even more havoc potentially. In that way it's not really very effective, but that would probably be asked for too much from sanctions.

So, if anyone says that the personal sanction of Putin will have a big impact, you would have all reason to be very skeptical about it.

As a summary: This sanction is partly symbolic and the real impact on Putin is difficult to say. It may be very low but is definitely not zero. We will never know for sure.